# Rendering Quote Marks in PHP String

Tags: php

I have a PHP function that outputs quote marks like so when rendered in the html.

```
onload="this.rel=&#039;stylesheet&#039;"
```

What I want is the following:

```
onload="this.rel='stylesheet'"
```

Here is the function causing the first example to happen - does anyone know how I can solve this?

```
public function get_css($opts, $index, $count)
    {
        $out = array();

                $version = filemtime($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/assets/css/app.min.css');
                $str = "this.rel='stylesheet'";
                $out[] = $this->_single_tag('link', array(
                    'rel'=>'preload',
                    'as'=>'style',
                    'type'=>'text/css',
                    'href'=>'/assets/css/app.min.'.$version.'.css',
                    'onload'=>$str,
                ));

        return implode("\n\t", $out)."\n";

    }
```

Here is the function for **_single_tag**

```
protected function _single_tag($tag=false, array $attrs)
{
    if ($tag===false) return;

    return PerchXMLTag::create($tag, 'single', $attrs);
}
```

Comment: Presumably your call to `$this->_single_tag()` is doing some HTML encoding which is converting the quote to an HTML tag. Can we see the source code for that function?

Comment: I have updated the question with the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the `PerchXMLTag::create()` method which does some HTML encoding on the values supplied to it.

Looking at [the Perch documentation](https://docs.grabaperch.com/api/reference/xmltag/) there doesn't seem to be a way to disable this, so my suggestion would be to replace the code within the `get_css` function with something that just outputs the raw HTML:

```
public function get_css($opts, $index, $count)
{
    $out = array();

    $version = filemtime($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/assets/css/app.min.css');
    $str = "this.rel='stylesheet'";
    $out[] = "<link rel='preload' as='style' type='text/css' href='/assets/css/app.min.{$version}.css' onload='{$str}' />";

    return implode("\n\t", $out)."\n";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function get_css($opts, $index, $count)
{
    $out = array();

            $version = filemtime($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/assets/css/app.min.css');
            $str = "this.rel=\"stylesheet\"";
            $out[] = $this->_single_tag('link', array(
                'rel'=>'preload',
                'as'=>'style',
                'type'=>'text/css',
                'href'=>'/assets/css/app.min.'.$version.'.css',
                'onload'=>$str,
            ));

    return implode("\n\t", $out)."\n";

}
```

Try with that.

Comment: Your example returns the following output: onload="this.rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot;"

Comment: Won't this code just return the same thing? Somewhere in his code the quotes are being HTML encoded, so just changing the single quote to a double quote won't actually fix this problem

Comment: Then is a problem with encoding. Make sure your Apache and your PHP instances are configured with utf-8 encoding.

In apache you can check in httpd.conf file: `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` and in PHP, in your php.ini file: `default_charset = "utf-8"`

Comment: There must be a call to `htmlspecialchars()` somewhere in the code which is causing this. It's nothing to do with file encoding.